# Can my Context Extension update the new object passed in

Tags: entity-framework

If I Add an object to my DbSet like this:

```
_db.KeywordGroup.Add(keyGroup);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

The object (keyGroup) get's the Id from the database.

I have a custom Extension I'm using where I try to do the same thing. Basically, I check to see if an object exists in the database. If it does, I would like the existing object returned with it's Id, if not, I want to add the object and get the new Id.

```
_db.KeywordGroup.AddIfNotExists(keyGroup, true,
    k => k.KeywordGroupName == keyGroup.KeywordGroupName);
_db.SaveChanges();

....

public static T AddIfNotExists<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, 
    T entity, 
    bool returnExists = false, 
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : class, new()
{
    var exists = predicate != null ? dbSet.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault() : dbSet.FirstOrDefault();
    if (exists == null || !returnExists) return exists == null ? dbSet.Add(entity) : null;
    entity = exists;
    return dbSet.Attach(entity);
}
```

However, I'm having trouble getting keyGroup to get the Id. How can I get my method to work similar to the default Add function, filling my object with the Id if I find a result.

Comment: What do you mean with "If it does, I would like the existing object returned with it's Id, if not, I want to add the object and get the new Id". Do you need to pass back *exists* to the caller? In this case mark the parameter T entity as ref T entity.

Comment: That was it, setting entity to ref works.